# Display a list of dynamic data, 10 rows each column, with header repeated each time extra column is added

Tags: html, css, dynamic, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have a dynamic data coming. I need to display them as a column, with 10 records in each row. I am able to display with 10 rows as expected. But I want the header to repeat each time an extra column is added. How can I achieve. I am using angular framework.

html code

```
<div class="section3BG" id="section3"
        style="margin-top: 24.9px;margin-left: 18px;margin-bottom: 23.9px;margin-right: 27px;">
        <div class="row" style="margin-left: 41px;padding-top: 23px;" *ngFor="let fac of facilities11">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2" class="Facility-Name-Heading">
                Facility Name
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2" class="Equipment" style="margin-left: 107px;">
                Equipment
            </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngFor="let facility of facilities">
            <div class="Rectangle-2001">
                <div class="row" style="margin-left: 21px;padding-top: 23px;">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2" class="Facility-Name-1">
                        Facility Name 1
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2" class="number" style="margin-left: 90px;">
                        10
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Css

```
.section3BG {
        width: 1785px;
        height: 825.1px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
        background-color: #ffffff;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column wrap;
        align-content: flex-start; 
      }

.Facility-Name-Heading {
        opacity: 0.5;
        font-family: Lato;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-stretch: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        line-height: 1.22;
        letter-spacing: 0.9px;
        text-align: left;
        color: #0d0d0d;
      }

.Equipment {
        //width: 94px;
        //height: 22px;
        opacity: 0.5;
        font-family: Lato;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-stretch: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        line-height: 1.22;
        letter-spacing: 0.9px;
        text-align: left;
        color: #000000;
      }

.Rectangle-2001 {
        width: 374px;
        height: 57px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: solid 1px #e9e9e9;
        background-color: rgba(236, 236, 236, 0.22);
        margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 15px;
      }
      .Facility-Name-1 {
        width: 134px;
        height: 22px;
        font-family: Lato;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 500;
        font-stretch: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        line-height: 1.22;
        letter-spacing: 0.9px;
        text-align: left;
        color: #487217;
      }
      .number{
            width: 22px;
            height: 22px;
            font-family: Lato;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: 500;
            font-stretch: normal;
            font-style: normal;
            line-height: 1.22;
            letter-spacing: 0.9px;
            text-align: left;
            color: #487217;
      }
```

expected image

[image]

What I am able to achieve

[image]

Comment: Can somebody please help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by including the header within the foreach loop. Code is as below

````
    <div *ngFor="let wareHouse of wareHouseList; let i = index">
      <div class="row facilityNameHeading" *ngIf="i % 10 == 0">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2" class="Facility-Name-Heading">
          Facility Name
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2" class="Equipment">
          Equipment
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        class="Rectangle-2001"
        (click)="navigateToDevicedashboard(wareHouse.id)"
      >
        <div class="row wareHouseName">
          <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2" class="Facility-Name-1">
            {{ wareHouse.name }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2" class="number">
            {{ wareHouse.noOfDevices }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>```
````